# How to draw a simple horizontal rule in a QWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I just want to add a horizontal rule (just like `<hr>` in HTML, see below) to a QWidget.

---

But I failed to find such a class in the documentation.
Could anyone give me example code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done using a `QFrame` and setting the shape with `setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine)` and frame shadow using `setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken)`. I just noticed that you are working in Python. My answer uses C++ syntax. Hopefully it is sufficient :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I thought it was something like 'Qline', now I know it is just a 'QFrame'.